# UWP Gridview Binding to ObservableCollection and clearing values

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp

so I am creating a GridView in a UWP app which is bound to an ObservableCollection.

XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="ListSource"
            Source="{x:Bind model.ShowList}"
            IsSourceGrouped="false"
            />
</Page.Resources>
...
<Page>
    <GridView x:Name="lvListSource" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ListSource}}" SelectedIndex="-1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="lvEpisodeListSource_SelectionChanged">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:PageInput">
                        <TextBlock Name="AlbumBlock" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="15" Margin="5,0,5,0"
                                    Text="{x:Bind Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
</page>
```

C#:

```
public MainCategoryModel model;
public MainPage()
{
    model = new MainCategoryModel();
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //initialize model data in code and stuff comes out correctly
    //model.Clear() give unknown error here
    model.Add(new PageInput() {...});
    lvListSource.ItemsSource = model.myList;
}

public class MainCategoryModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<PageInput> myList { get; set; }

    public MainCategoryModel()
    {
        myList = new ObservableCollection<PageInput>();
    }

    public void AddShow(PageInput show)
    {
        myList.Insert(0, show);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        myList.Clear();
    }
}
```

The ObservableCollection initializes properly and the page loads perfectly fine when I only add items to the collection. The problem is, I would like to update this ObservableCollection the GridView is bound to every time the OnNavigatedTo function is called. This includes removing items from the collection. Every time I either remove items or try to Clear the ObservableCollection the page fails to load with an unknown error. Is there a way to modify and remove values from an Observable Collection that is already bound to?

As a side problem, If I don't re-set the ItemsSource property at the end of OnNavigatedTo, the SelectionChanged event is called immediately after adding values to the Collection since it is set in XAML. Is there a way to have the SelectionChanged event not call when items are added to a GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x:Bind is OneTime by default, you need to set it Mode=OneWay to get the layout updates

```
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
       //initialize model data in code and stuff comes out correctly

      lvEpisodeListSource.ItemsSource = model.myList;
   }
```

kills your binding, update model.myList and let the binding do the job, don't set ItemsSource from code this way if you want it to be binded

edit:

copied and run your code (which wasn't pleasant experience because you didn't make it clean) and I don't undersand why there is such mess with the Binding and x:Bind in your code, why don't you just bind the collection like that?

```
<GridView x:Name="lvListSource" ItemsSource="{x:Bind model.myList, Mode=OneWay}" ....
```

edit2:

my code:

```
public class MainCategoryModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<PageInput> myList { get; set; }

    public MainCategoryModel()
    {
        myList = new ObservableCollection<PageInput>();
    }

    public void AddShow(PageInput show)
    {
        myList.Insert(0, show);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        myList.Clear();
    }
}

<Page>
(........)
    <GridView x:Name="lvListSource" ItemsSource="{x:Bind model.myList, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedIndex="-1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:PageInput">
            <TextBlock Name="AlbumBlock" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="15" Margin="5,0,5,0"
                                Text="{x:Bind Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainCategoryModel model;
    public MainPage()
    {
        model = new MainCategoryModel();
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        model.Clear();
        model.myList.Add(new PageInput() {Name = "testName"});
    }
```

}

and made by quess:

```
public class PageInput
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

try to run and check it

Comment: If I remove this though I still get the same problem of it crashing when i try to remove an item from the collection though. It also automatically calls my SelectionChanged event when I add items if I don't have that.

Comment: took your code and made it runnable, please check edit

Comment: Hello, that binding worked perfectly! Was not aware you could do it like that. It all works perfectly on the first run, but each item has a SelectionChanged event which calls another page. Added in edit for you. When I use the built-in App back button I get an unhandled XAML error when I hit the Clear() function.

Comment: Sorry about being so difficult! Thanks so much for helping! So if you navigate to another page from here and then navigate back to the MainPage, the Clear function inside the OnNavigated to causes the unhandled XAML exception.

Comment: @kennywitham I cannot reproduce this issue. Could you please share a [mcve]?

Comment: @KennyWitham updated my project with the selectionchanged event you have provided and navigation chain (except passing PageModel as I don't know how it looks like) and it works fine, problem must be within something else in your code

Comment: Thanks so much for helping guys! Sorry this was such a mess. I'll mark this one as complete for the binding issue since that works now. I will open another question that is a lot more organized for this.

Comment: Actually, issue was page caching!! Totally have no idea why I didn't see that line of code buried in my mess and forgot I added it. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Clearing a data object object that XAML code is bound to gives Unknown error when Page caching is turned on. Disabling page caching allows you to clear objects correctly.

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;
```

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022646/uwp-gridview-binding-to-observablecollection-and-clearing-values) that's already in the community

Comment: Your attached link is actually to this current thread. So what do we do if we want to clear an ObservableCollection while navigating to a cached page?