# Trying to bind make a gridview autoupdate in uwp c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, windowsiot, dbgrid

i want to make a dbgrid update data from a list when i write into it in a uwp. Because you set the datasource in xaml i cant seem to find a way to auto update it? i have tried to use a observablecollection but i cant seem to figure out how it works.

```
            foreach (var item in dataAccess.GetData())
            {
                cars.Add(item);
            }
```

this is how i read the values into the list and it runs on a timer so it will add data every time the timer ticks and then the data should display in the dbgrid.

```
List<CarSimulation> cars = new List<CarSimulation>();
```

that is how i declaired the lsit that i am using to bind the data to the dbgrid and because i am reading the data from a sqlite database first the dbgrid does not display anything. any tips on how i can update it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `List` into `ObservableCollection`. `ObservableCollection` is a collection class that provides notifications when items get added or removed.

```
ObservableCollection<CarSimulation> cars = new ObservableCollection<CarSimulation>();
```

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022646/uwp-gridview-binding-to-observablecollection-and-clearing-values) that's already in the community

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<SPSystem_UW_.CarSimulation>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SPSystem_UW_.CarSimulation>' SPSystem(UW) error in the mainpage.g.cs 'this.Update_cars(obj.cars, phase);` and i dont know whats wrong because i havent changed anything in this page?

Comment: You are copying ObservableCollection to a List